# Python communicating with serial device

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, serial-communication

The device external communication is through **asynchronous** **serial (TTL level)**, N, 8, 1, 115200b/s, without checkout.

The general command frame has 19 bytes, including frame head, address, command length, command word, data exchange segment, frame number, and checkout. (as shown in table1)

For example selecting the device mode we follow Table#2 :

[Table#1 and #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abnhi.png)

The code I came up with so far looks like this:

```
import serial   # use the serial module 

import time     # delay functions


ser = serial.Serial(“COM10”, 115200, timeout=1) #Change the COM PORT NUMBER to match your device

if ser.isOpen():    # make sure port is open

print(ser.name + ‘ open…’)    # tell the user we are starting

 
#Servo Modes Control 

Mode = int(input("Select Servo Mode:"))

# Mode = OFF

if mode = 1: 
    import array
    tmp = array.array('B', [0x01, 0x69, 0x00]).tostring()
    ser.write(tmp.encode())
    ser.close()

# Mode Manual

elif mode = 2:
    import array
    tmp = array.array('B', [0x01, 0x69, 0x01]).tostring()
    ser.write(tmp.encode())
    ser.close()

# Mode Lock Mode

elif mode = 3:
    import array
    tmp = array.array('B', [0x01, 0x69, 0x02]).tostring()
    ser.write(tmp.encode())
    ser.close()

#Mode Azimuth Scan

elif mode = 4:
    import array
    tmp = array.array('B', [0x01, 0x69, 0x1B]).tostring()
    ser.write(tmp.encode())
    ser.close()

# Zero Mode

elif mode = 3:
    import array
    tmp = array.array('B', [0x01, 0x69, 0x09]).tostring()
    ser.write(tmp.encode())
    ser.close()

# Freeze Mode

elif mode = 4:
    import array
    tmp = array.array('B', [0x01, 0x69, 0x0B]).tostring()
    ser.write(tmp.encode())
    ser.close()
```

***NOTE: I am a beginner and this code dose not work so far! please advice me on what I should do!!!***

Thanks!!

Comment: If you're dealing with protocol like documentation, it's better to treat all the data as bytes-like objects instead of `tostring()` or `encode()`. Also, `tostring()` has changed from python 3.2 to `tobytes()`. The material you are referring to may be an old `python 2.x` series, so please reselect the reference material.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working? You have a few lines checking if ports are open - do these behave as expected?

Regarding if statements:
The first thing I notice is that you have used the assignment operator, "=" in an if statement. You need to use comparison operator "==" to check if variables equal something specific within your if statement.

I suspect this may help in your initial troubleshooting. Try just checking one if condition since you are so new to programming.